# Verify iPhone 4 encryption status?

Tags: security, exchange, encryption, iphone, activesync

After enabling "require encryption on the device" in ActiveSync policies, how does one verify that the policy has been applied successfuly on an iPhone 4 (or iPhone 3GS) running iOS 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When encryption is enabled, the phone will indicate "Data protection is enabled" at the bottom of the **Settings -> General -> Passcode Lock** menu.  Note that encryption is enabled automatically whenever the passcode lock feature is enabled, so the "require encryption on the device" policy has no additional effect on iOS 4 devices if a passcode is already required.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4175